How do I grant a role to CURRENT_USER in Snowflake?
I am creating a portable SQL script. The CURRENT_USER may vary but I want to always grant role X to them. I have tried the following which fail:

GRANT ROLE X to CURRENT_USER;
GRANT ROLE X to CURRENT_USER();


both with Syntax error: unexpected 'CURRENT_USER'. (line 1)

Is there a way to do this?

Grant something to yourself? (CURRENT_USER is the one performing the GRANT ROLE statement.)

Yes. The current user has ACCOUNTADMIN but not the desired role.

yeesh, don't tell your security folks...

Using a session variable:
SET name = (SELECT CURRENT_USER());   
GRANT ROLE X TO USER IDENTIFIER($name);


I found one way to do this, but I suspect there's a better way.
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  stmt STRING;
BEGIN
  stmt := CONCAT('GRANT ROLE X TO USER ', CURRENT_USER(), ';');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
END;
$$
;

